# Как собрать INSERT запрос в PLPGSQL в цикле LOOP чтобы он выполнился один раз?

Tags: plpgsql

Есть цикл

```
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$
DECLARE
rec record;

BEGIN

FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM public.users  
LOOP
INSERT INTO public.user_task(user_id, task_id, meta, status)
    VALUES (rec.id, 15, '{"sender":"pablo","body":"they are on to us"}', 'uncomplete');

END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

Насколько я понимаю, вставок будет ровно столько, сколько и строк в таблице `users`

Можно ли как-то собрать этот запрос в один, чтобы была одна вставка?

Comment: INSERT INTO public.user_task(user_id, task_id, meta, status) select rec.id, 15, '{"sender":"pablo","body":"they are on to us"}', 'uncomplete' from public.users rec; всего один запрос вместо цикла

Comment: @Konst, спасибо, работает, слишком сложным путем я пошел :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

достаточно выполнить один запрос вместо цикла:

```
INSERT INTO public.user_task(user_id, task_id, meta, status) select rec.id, 15, '{"sender":"pablo","body":"they are on to us"}', 'uncomplete' from public.users rec;
```